# ¿Existe alguna palabra en español para la palabra del Inglés "Snowflake"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Como se podría traducir al español la palabra en Inglés "Snowflake" como es utilizada en este contexto: Cuando los "snowflakes" tienen una cita.

[When snowflakes date](https://www.facebook.com/YourPageIsFunny/videos/10155691381783386/)

Según este link [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake_(slang)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake_(slang)) . Su significado ha variado, pero puede incluir a una persona con un inflado sentido de unicicidad, que tiene un injustificado sentido de derecho propio, o que se ofende facilmente y es incapaz de lidiar con opiniones opuestas.

Comment: Un _snowflake_ es un copo de nieve. Entiendo que te estás refiriendo a algún tipo de contexto que el vídeo que enlazas aporta; sin embargo, tampoco no es nuestra función interpretar esa connotación, sino que es algo que deberías aportarnos tú para que, en base a ello, podamos discernir cuál es tu duda. Resumiendo: clarifica por favor qué entiendes que quiere decir _snowflake_ en el contexto del vídeo que enlazas; a partir de allí, podremos ayudarte.

Comment: Snowflake se usa para referirse a cierto tipo de personas. Desconozco todas las connotaciones que tiene, pero creo que una y deduciendo del video es las personas que se ofenden facilmente.

Comment: Pero es que en tal caso sería más bien una pregunta para [english.se]. Si no conoces con precisión la connotación de un término es deseable que primero la clarifiques. De lo contrario, ¿cómo podrás validar si las respuestas que te demos son válidas?

Comment: ok, según este link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake_(slang) . Su significado ha variado, pero puede incluir a una persona con un inflado sentido de unicicidad, que tiene un injustificado sentido de derecho propio, o que se ofende facilmente y es incapaz de lidiar con  opiniones opuestas.

Comment: Ajá, 'eso es mucha información útil que ayudaría a perfilar mejor la pregunta! Recomiendo añadirla, pues a bote pronto ya me sugirió la palabra _quisquilloso_.

Comment: Parece bastante poco probable que haya un equivalente en castellano, puesto que se trata de un uso bastante nuevo en inglés. Yo sólo conozco gente que usa el término inglés original y gente que no lo usa en absoluto porque desconoce el concepto.

Comment: hmmmm asi que viene del 96/99 de alguien que se cree único sobre todo (como los copos de nieve que se creen que son únicos y distintos a cualquier otro). Entonces supongo que la traducción correcta al español debería ser la traducción literal.

Comment: ... no tiene callo... una princesita....

Comment: @aparente001 que quiere decir eso?

Comment: El callo protege la piel de las irritaciones.  El que no tiene callo is muy vulnerable.  La princesita está acostumbrada a ser el centro de su universo.

Comment: ahh serían 2 opciones.

Comment: De acuerdo con @aparente había propuesto "maricón" pero eso tiene muchas connotaciones sexuales. "Princesita" es entendible en ese sentido, pero tal vez "delicadito" cubre más de los significados metafóricos de *snowflake* siendo mas panhispánico y evitando entrar en los pantanosos terrenos del machismo.

Comment: @hlecuanda - Me gusta *delicado*.  Personalmente pienso que se podría borrar *maricón.* // Otra idea, *pusilánime*, que encontré en linguee, cuando busqué *thin-skinned*.

Comment: Pusilánime es mucho más cercano a "deplorable" que a snowflake. xD y si creo que delicadito se entiende en cualquier lugar sin connotaciones extras o equipaje de otras índoles.

Answer (score 4):

Otra probable palabra equivalente sería

> **Delicado/delicada**

que tal vez es más panhispánico que maricón, ya que esta palabra tiene fuertes connotaciones regionales sobre todo de "afeminado".

El diminutivo de la misma podría dar mayor énfasis a las connotaciones de *snowflake* pudiendo entenderse de manera más universal en diversas regiones hispanoparlantes.

Ejemplo conversacional:

> -En Tijuana hubo una marcha protestando por la construcción del Muro de Trump.
>
> -¡Huy! ¡Qué ***delicaditos!*** En Palestina llevamos más de 10 años con un muro similar y nadie se queja.

Answer (score 2):

En Chile decimos que alguien es **delicado de cutis** cuando es exageradamente susceptible y no se le puede hacer críticas.

Comment: En España decimos algo parecido: _tiene la piel muy fina_.

Answer (score 0):

Bajo la reserva de que en inglés este término es ampliamente peyorativo, divisivo, ofensivo, inflamatorio, altamente politizado y poco conducente al objetivo real del lenguaje que es comunicar ideas y no ofender y hacer de menos a tu interlocutor individual o colectivo, apunto que las respuestas a esta pregunta seguramente Irán en la misma vena, y por más tentación que tuviésemos de moderar severamente la pregunta o sus respuestas, **no deja de ser una pregunta válida**.

También es una pregunta oportuna, ya que en el país hispanoparlante más próximo a los Estados Unidos, de donde se origina el término, estamos pasando por una intensa campaña electoral, y la tentacion de usar símiles verbales a los que se usaron en las controversiales elecciones del 16 es muy grande.

Dicho esto, en el sentido más amplio de la palabra, en México usaríamos el soez y sexista:

> **Maricón**

Que básicamente abarca todos los sentidos apuntados en la pregunta.

Comment: hmmm en mi pais se usa maricón y no veo que se parezca a como usan snowflake en Inglés. A no ser que en tu país y en el mio se use de forma diferente. Se usa para un hombre que no tiene valor (coraje) y/o que le gustan los hombres. Me parece que falla sobre todo en la connotación de persona que se cree muy especial (aparte de ofenderse por cualquier cosa)

Comment: Es probable, que se use distinto que en México. Además de tener una fuerte connotación de "afeminado", en México abarca tácitamente el sentido que en inglés se le ha dado últimamente. Alguien que se queja por todo lo que no va como el quisiera, haciéndose la víctima, siendo sumamente "delicado" como los copos de nieve

Comment: @walen (solo enumerando hechos, aclaro que no comparto esa opinión) Siendo "Maricón" un peyorativo altisonante de medio pelo (los hay más indignantes y soeces) desde luego se da por hecho el rancio sexismo implícito en la palabra: no se usaría para mujeres, porque no se esperaría que las damas tuviesen ninguna clase de intereses en la política. Insisto, no comparto esa opinión pero la palabra refleja el rancio y retrógrado ambiente cultural en el que se fragua

Comment: @walen Últimamente, sobre todo entre  los millenials de la comunidad LGBTQ han empezado a usar **"maricona"** entre sus miembros en algunas ocasiones y con otra acepción muy distinta, implicando mas bien *temor* o *cobardía*. Se aplica a quienes expresan su identidad sexual como Femenina, independientemente de sus preferencias  Por otro lado, fuera de la comunidad LGBTQ, no se esperaría el aplicar el femenino de "maricón" pues sería una paradoja: Maricon implica feminizar y por ende *(según)* humillar a tu interlocutor que desde luego es muy *macho*,

Answer (score 0):

Además de **quisquilloso** ---como ya apuntó @fedorqui--- se me ocurren:

> **picajoso**. Que fácilmente se pica o da por ofendido.

> **susceptible**. Quisquilloso, picajoso.

> **impresionable**. Fácil de impresionar o propenso a recibir una impresión

Answer (score 0):

La sobreprotección de los niños y jóvenes por parte de los padres redunda en una menor tolerancia al fracaso y la frustración, provocando una personalidad hipervulnerable que difícilmente soporta lo que no entra dentro de su *círculo de confort*, lo que incluye también los gustos y opiniones.

Este **síndrome del niño consentido**, que se materializa en la asunción de que son especiales y únicos (como un copo de nieve, *snowflake* en inglés) impide o dificulta el desarrollo de una autoestima positiva, de tal modo que cuando han de enfrentarse a un problema, tomar una decisión o confrontar una opinión contraria, no son capaces de darle una solución o respuesta.

En lugar de ello, aparece una reacción a la "ofensa", ya que es así como se sienten. Por eso en ocasiones se usa la expresión "**ofendiditos**", un término muy negativo que puede ser el equivalente de esta acepción de **snowflake**.

Aunque el término ya se usaba en el siglo XXI, no tenía la connotación que se le da a partir de la década de 2010. Existe cierto acuerdo en tomar como punto de partida un monólogo que aparece en la novela *El club de la lucha* (Chuck Palahniuk, 1996) popularizada poco después por la película homónima dirigida por David Fincher en 1999:

> You are not special. You are not a beautiful and unique snowflake. (No eres especial. No eres un precioso y único copo de nieve).

Si bien la expresión completa es **Snowflake Generation** (Generación Copo de nieve) es cada más habitual usarla en su forma abreviada, **snowflake**.

---

**Referencias**

- [Generación Copo de nieve](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copo_de_nieve_(jerga))